# Finding news articles by date on GoogleNewsSource in tm.plugin.webmining in R

Tags: r, date, tm

I would like to use the `GoogleNewsSource()` function to get articles from Google news using the `tm.plugin.webmining` package. I want a time series from 2000-2015 of news articles per month, in order to conduct some analysis.

What is the best way to collect a sample of news articles related to "US Economy" for that time period, arranged in order per month?

I have tried the following code:

```
library("tm")
library("tm.plugin.webmining")
googlenews <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource("US economy", since="1-1-2015", until="31-1-2015"))
```

It simply returns a list of 30 of the latest news articles.

Comment: @Pascal Hi, I just updated the codes I have used.

Comment: I don't see any "since" and "until" arguments in `GoogleNewsSource`. Also, according to your post, you want since 1-1-2000, not since 1-1-2015.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering if there are any equivalent such arguments in GoogleNewsSource that I could use @Pascal

Comment: Read the help page `?GoogleNewsSource`.

Comment: Yes I have, the information is incomplete. Thanks anyway. @Pascal

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define it with a parameter within the params=list() argument. I found many parameters for google search [here](http://i-tweak.blogspot.gr/2013/10/google-news-search-parameters-missing.html).

It should be the ones listed under `as_drrb=b` .